# how to add @expo/vector-icons in react native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

i am using @expo/vector-icons here is my package.json file

```
 "dependencies": {
     "@expo/vector-icons": "^4.1.1",
     "color": "^1.0.3",
     "expo": "^30.0.1",
     "moment": "^2.22.2",
     "react": "16.3.1",
     "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk- 
      30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.4.0"  },
```

when i import  @expo/vector-icon library in my component

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

it gives error 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dependencies (package.json) remove @expo/vector-icons. They are included in the expo package and different versions of expo and expo/vector-icons can cause errors like this one.

From the [official docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons):

> This library is installed by default on the template project that get
> through expo init -- it is part of the expo package. It includes
> popular icon sets and you can browse all of the icons using the
> @expo/vector-icons directory.

Update 2021:
The official docs changed a bit, and instead of searching for icons in:

> @expo/vector-icons directory

You can now search using:

[icons.expo.fyi](https://icons.expo.fyi)

This makes it far easier than before.

Comment: yes but what name to use when specifying the icon you want to use?

Comment: Well, the question is about React Native app, not expo... so, not sure how your answer applies here.

Comment: @VladMiller OP IS using Expo... Have a look at the dependencies. Also, this solved OP's issue, hence the "accepted answer" mark.

Comment: @c-chavez if you eject, expo will still stay in the list of dependencies. Hence, the question (or the answer) is misleading. The answer does not apply to non-expo RN, or OP should mention that it's an RN app that uses expo.

Comment: @VladMiller OP also added Expo in the tags, and imho if both Dependencies and Tags show "Expo" it looks like OP is in fact using Expo. If OP wasn't, OP should clarify, which OP did not. Since OP marked it as an answer, and the answer is to remove `@expo/vector-icons` as a dependency, it looks like OP is indeed using Expo (this is a typical issue when using both dependencies, as it did happen to me before). Of course if OP is not using Expo, another answer should be written and chosen, and I'm completely OK with it :)

Answer (score 1):

The library comes by default so you don't need to install @expo/vector-icons.

You can just do this for example:

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

and then you can use it like:

```
<Ionicons name="ios-pizza" color="red" size={200} />
```

FYI, this directory is helpful in finding different icons https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/

Comment: It is not working with react-native@0.72.4. It is asking for expo-font after install

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'https://icons.expo.fyi/' choose whatever you want, then import via copy, then use it.

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import { View } from 'react-native';

    export const Example = () => {
      return(
        <View>
          <Entypo name="plus" size={24} color="black" />
        </View>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your node module folder and run expo init. And run the project